# Role based authorization using OpenIddict

Tags: openiddict

Im currently setting up an authorization server with a separate resource server using OpenIddict and a SPA frontend. Everything is working fine apart from 1 thing. Role based authorization on endpoints from the resource server. My controller on the resource server looks as follows;

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore;
using System.Security.Claims;

namespace TestProtectedApi.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

        public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Authorize(Roles = "ADMIN")]
        [HttpGet("GetWeatherForecast")]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(index)),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }

        [Authorize]
        [HttpGet("GetWeatherForecastNoRole")]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> GetNoRole()
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(index)),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Authorization itself works fine. When i call the endpoint when im not logged in it gives an 401 and when i am logged in and call the endpoint without role based authorization it gives the data. Alot of people with the same issue as mine needed to add the request for the "roles" scope. I already request it and it also adds it to the access_token as seen in the following picture where i decode it in jwt.io;
[image]

And this is what happens when i try to call the role based endpoint when logged in:
[image]

Here is my Program.cs for my resourceserver:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowAllOrigins",
        builder =>
        {
            builder
                .AllowCredentials()
                .WithOrigins(
                    "http://localhost:4200", "http://localhost:4204", "https://localhost:7150")
                .SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod();
        });
});

builder.Services.AddOpenIddict()
    .AddValidation(options =>
    {
        // Note: the validation handler uses OpenID Connect discovery
        // to retrieve the address of the introspection endpoint.
        options.SetIssuer("https://localhost:7150/");

        options.UseIntrospection()
            .SetClientId("api_server")
            .SetClientSecret("test");

        // Register the System.Net.Http integration.
        options.UseSystemNetHttp();

        // Register the ASP.NET Core host.
        options.UseAspNetCore();
    });

builder.Services.AddCors();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.UseCors("AllowAllOrigins");

app.Run();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to answering stacks..

Though I have a working **Client >> Auth >>**

Resource using Authorization.

**Authorize(Role="Admin")**  if Admin is assigned correctly works in my app.

Note the client must have "**Role**" scope in startup

```
 Scopes = { 
             OpenIddict.Abstractions.OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.Email, 
             OpenIddict.Abstractions.OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.Profile, 
             OpenIddict.Abstractions.OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.Roles 
           },
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to override the AuthorizeHandler in custom implementation you have claimInfo so you can check the authorization and make your decission authorize. image is attached for reference it will help you in implemenation.